# SQL server query requesting too much memory

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am running a fairly simple query (LEFT JOINing a few tables on their primary keys) but SQL server is asking for a large amount of memory to run this query:
[image]

This results in only a few queries being run at a time. Is there a way to force less memory to be granted or for less memory to be requested per query?
I am using SQL server 2012 (not the enterprise version), and I have tried reducing the `Max degree of parallelism` and increasing the `parallelism threshold` without much change in the memory requirements.

Comment: If you look at the execution plan, what is the memory being requested for?

Comment: This sounds like a question which would serve more purpose on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you paste execution plan here:https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: "to run this query"? How about showing the query?

Comment: The query plan is larger than 2 MB, so I can't put it on brentozar.com

Comment: You have a 2MB query plan? In XML?

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly using ALL PK columns in the joins? Sounds to me like some kind of cartesian product or something...

Comment: Why do you feel SQL Server, and this query are consuming too much memory? What end problem are you trying to solve? If SQL Server is consuming too much in general, set the max memory it can use on the server to leave room for other processes. In general, you should allow SQL Server to manage its own memory. That said: check that datatypes in tables are appropriate (excessive usage of (n)varchar(max) fields), limit the number of columns returned, ensure that all join fields are the same datatypes to limit in memory conversion, etc...